# How can I authenticate HTTP request calling the SP 2019 REST API, if the SP site is configured to use Windows Claims Based Authentication?

Tags: authentication, sharepoint

I'm writing a small tool that accesses data in a SharePoint 2019.
That SharePoint 2019 is configured to use "Windows Claims Based Authentication"; this means that from Windows machines part of the correct domain, users simply open the SharePoint site from Edge and the simply ***have*** access, without being prompted for credentials.

**QUESTION**: how could I authenticate the HTTP request to the SharePoint REST API that my tool does ?

I tried going in "private browsing"; there I **was** prompted for credentials, but I could not see any authentication header in the HTTP requests, so I don't know exactly how does the process look (so that I can "reproduce" it in my tool...).

Comment: could you please share a bit more info about what kind of a tool will it be? and if it will run under a user context or unattended execution?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/context-token-oauth-flow-for-sharepoint-add-ins i am sharing a link that's general enough in hope that it might help

Comment: @jimas13 I'll look over that.
A basic tool written in python, executed from CMD, on a machine which has network connection to the SP just like any normal SP user would have (so **not** on the SP server or anything like that), doing HTTP requests...

Comment: okay. are you going to use a users credentials or would like to create a deamon app that operates via a client ?

Comment: I need to use simple users credentials...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/116239/sharepoint-2016-get-access-token.html have you tried this approach using postman? you could set a get request to http://your-url/_api/contextinfo with NTLM Authentication in the Authorization tab using a domain acount and transfer the token, that you got from the inital request, to all the subsequent requests.